# How to switch between window and context in a windows app automation testing

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium, winappdriver

Can anyone help me on the tech stack,
I'm writing an automation testing for an electron app, that loads pages in the webview. So, I've to switch between the window and the webview.

I find Appium but seems the context switch is not supporting in windows.
With WinAppDriver can we do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe check here?: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, context switching is not supported.
If your tests open a window in Chromium web-view then you can try to test it with appropriate Selenium WebDriver. You'll create an instance using the HWND of the target WebView window.